# ScrollView and FrameLayout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have an activity that contains a FrameLayout that will have a dynamic length according to the content .. 
The FrameLayout is contained within a ScrollView, as you can see from the picture ..

[Image](http://imageshack.com/a/img853/2050/3s6w.png)

calculate the height of the frameLayout, using the following function, it moves the position of the scroll and does not start from the point (0,0), but the starting point of the FrameLayout to see the controls above it is necessary to scroll the view.

```
public void calcolaAltezza() {
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = sectionAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += divisoreLista + listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    listaTour.getLayoutParams().height = totalHeight;

    sv.scrollTo(0,0); //DON'T WORK

}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You want the ScrollView to start form somewhere else or at 0,0?

Comment: no, i want scrollView start at (0,0), but if FrameLayout is at (0,100), scrollview start to (0,100)

Comment: It looks like you have other views above the frame layout why not just get the left corner of the lowest view and scroll to that?